# Recreating the scrolling effect from Google Analytics docs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, custom-scrolling

The docs for Google Analytics: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/#the_javascript_tracking_snippet

has a fantastic scroll effect, where the left sidebar is the fixed height of the page, then increases in size as you scroll down, then shrinks down as you get to the bottom.

you can also scroll this sidebar independently of the main content...

is there an existing solution (or even a collection of solutions I could chain together), perhaps via jquery plugins, to achieve something similar?

right now i've been able to achieve something similar to MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt607689.aspx

by affixing the content on scroll (similar to bootstraps affix component) but the height of this container extends beyond the height of the browser so we have to scroll to the bottom to make the sidebar scroll.

the solution on the google analytics page is much more elegant because they scroll independently. any existing solution would be useful, and I'd like to know if there is one before I try to build it myself :)

Comment: I think I'm realizing the bigger problem is how to auto-size the left column based on scroll so that it's always taking up the maximum height, whether you scroll or resize the browser, so if I can at least have some insight on that, I think i might be set!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll/?

They appears to work the same way as the reference page.